# "In the point (1,2)" or "In point (1,2)"?

Tags: mathematics

In questions from a mathematics test, what is the correct phrasing of the following sentence?

> Compute the function value in **the** point (x,y)=(1,2).

> Compute the function value in point (x,y)=(1,2).

We are here referring to a specific point, so I would argue that "the point" is appropriate. But it doesn't sound right or feel like proper English phrasing.

Comment: I'm not sure how to "refute" your "argument" here, but the fact of the matter is that most native speakers *wouldn't* include the article in your cited context. And this is nothing to do with "correct / incorrect" phrasing. It's simply a stylistic choice where we nearly all have the *same* idiomatic preference. Personally, I have no particular opinion as regards the choice between ***in*** and ***at*** here.

Comment: A point is one dimensional which makes it impossible to be **in** the point.  In English the commonly used preposition is **at**.  *Compute the function **at** point (1,2).*  You can use *the* or leave it out.  It sounds natural either way.

Comment: @EllieK and FumbleFingers, alright, what I get from this is that the article "the" is not important and can be added or omitted with no issue - but the "in a point" should always be "at a point" in general. Any exceptions to this or is this a general rule?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other commenters that this is somewhat a stylistic choice. But I believe I can cobble together some "rules" that describe the choices I have seen and heard in my math and engineering classes.

1. **Variables.**
   Variables do not take an article.

- Notation: *x*=*vt*|<sub>*t*=12</sub>
- Speech: Ecks equals vee tee, evaluated at [time] tee equals twelve.

2. **Points, without mentioning coordinate plane.**
   "Bare" points do not take an article.

- Notation: *f*=*x*<sup>2</sup>*y*|<sub>(3,5)</sub>
- Speech: Eff equals ecks-squared wye, evaluated at [point] three, five.

3. **Points, mentioning coordinate plane.**
   When referencing axis names, points do take an article.

- Notation: *f*=*x*<sup>2</sup>*y*|<sub>(x,y)=(3,5)</sub>
- Speech: Eff equals ecks-squared wye, evaluated at the point ecks, wye equals three, five.

So in your case I would argue for including the definite article **the**, both when writing the sentence and when speaking it out loud. The fact that it doesn't sound proper is likely due to the unnatural preposition **in** rather than **at**.

Answer (score 0):

> We are here referring to a specific point

"Specific" is really only part of story when talking about articles, and creates problems because it's a philosophical question sometimes whether an expression of noun X is an instance of X (meaning specific is possible) or an abstract "blueprint" or class/type/kind of X (meaning specific is sometimes not possible).  Another part is whether or not the writer/speaker expects the listener/reader to know what he/she is talking about.

So:

> Compute the function value in the point (x,y)=(1,2).

This implies:

- The question "which X"--where X is either "(x,y)=(1,2)" or some related linguistic object that can contain or be "(x,y)=(1,2)"--matters and is possible.
- Speaker/writer expects you to already know "which X" he/she is talking about.

and is 100% subjective according to speaker/writer.

As the speaker/writer - unless there are multiple *somethings* with (x,y)=(1,2) points on them and you think the listener/reader should know which one, the question doesn't matter, and the *the* should be omitted.