# In maths, should I write "at a point" or "in a point"

Tags: grammar, mathematics

In [another question I posted this evening](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/314658/in-the-point-1-2-or-in-point-1-2), a comment indicated that my use of "a/in" is wrong. Consider the following two sentences that could appear in a mathematics test:

> Compute the function value **in** point (x,y)=(1,2).

> Compute the function value **at** point (x,y)=(1,2).

I have always consistently used *in a point* since it matches my mothertongue (in Danish we would say *i et punkt*). But I have no actual argument for using it in English. Which version should I actually use? *In* or *at*?

Answer (score 3):

You should use **at**.

By definition, a point is dimensionless. A point has no area, no circumference. It does not make sense to say that there can be anything "in" a point, and so using that preposition sounds wrong to me. A point does, however, have a location, and so it makes sense to say "at a point" (meaning at the *location* of that point).

However, I would suggest more edits to your sentence:

1. "The function value" may perhaps be construed as an acceptable construction, if we extend the benefit of the doubt, but it is much more natural to show *possession*; we want to compute the value *that is associated with the function* and we express that by saying the value *belongs to* the function. So you should use either:

> the function's value [acceptable but less common]
> the value of the function [more common]

2. You must use an article for the noun in question. In this case, you are talking about a very specific point, so use the definite article: "value at **the** point." (I am specifically disagreeing with LawrenceC's answer on your linked question.)
3. ...but really, saying "point" is not necessary at all. You can remove it (and its associated article) and the sentence will still mean exactly what you want it to mean, but more concisely.

So here is my suggestion for the final sentence:

> Compute the value of the function at (x,y)=(1,2).

Comment: Perhaps a better preposition would be **for**. However this is only used when referring to *variables* rather than *geometric points*. Because it refers to variables, you would treat the inputs as an array and use square brackets instead of round brackets: *Compute the value for [x,y]=[1,2].*

Comment: Or, if you are a mathematician the shorthand "compute f(2,3)" would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

"In" is incorrect.  In this context the word "point" has a specific mathematical meaning.  The point has no shape or size itself and is used solely as a way of referencing a geometric location. You are not "in" anything but "at" somewhere.  I have seen many include "at" but drop  "the" which I personally mind less when discussing multiple points.

Compute the value of the function *f* **at the points** (1,2), (3,4), ...

Compute the value of the function *f* **at the point** (1,2)

Compute the value of the function *f* **at points** (1,2), (3,4), ...

If you replace "point" with "coordinates," it would follow the same pattern:

"at the coordinates" not "in the coordinates"